# JTable : 'An error occured while communicating with the server ' while updating or deleting records

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-jtable

I am kind of stuck in this problem for hours until now.

I am trying to update the record of a row of jTable by deleting or editing it, but every time I am facing the same error ( i.e An error occured during the communication with server ).

I tried a lot to solve this but until now no succeed at all.

I am successfully able to add record ( i.e an object of class 'Professor' ). But editing is not being performed and respective object's ( i.e Professor) controller's HTTPPost enabled method is not being executed.

I attached the screenshot.

[image]

Moreover, following is jTable code in view.

```
<div id="ProfessorTableContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#ProfessorTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Professor List',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: false,
            actions:
            {
                listAction:   '@Url.Action("GetProfessors")',
                deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteProfessor")',
                updateAction: '@Url.Action("UpdateProfessor")',
                createAction: '@Url.Action("CreateProfessor")'
            },
            fields: {
                ProfessorId:
                 {
                     key: true,
                     create: false,
                     edit: false,
                     list: false
                 },
                ProfessorName:
                {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '23%'
                }

            }

        });
        $('#ProfessorTableContainer').jtable('load');
        //Load all records when page is first shown

    });
```

and following is the code snippet of Controller's Update Method or Delete method.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteProfessor(int  profId)
        {
            try
            {
                ProfRepository.DeleteProfessor(profId);
                return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

I would be very much obliged is somebody helps me out.
I am kind of stuck in this and don't know how to solve this. I have seen all the areas, everything seems perfect and fine enough.

Regards
Usman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**reason 1** : crud methods parameter name must **"record"** 
example : public static object(Product record)

**reason 2** : Model class must parameterless constructor 
example :  public Product() {}